# overriding a const method of the Base class from the derived class

Tags: c++, class, overloading, overriding

```
class Base{
//...
    public:
    int get()const{ // const
    // Do something.
     }
    int get(int x){
    // Do Someting.
     }

    //...

};
class Derived:public Base{
//....
     public:
     int get(){ // not const (not the same signature as the one is the base class) 
     //Dosomething
     }
      //...

};
```

I know that get() in Derived class will hide get() and get(int x) methods inside Base class. so My question is:
*1)* is this consedred overloading or overriding ?
*2)* does making get() const in the derived class will change something about (hiding or not hiding Base class methods).

Quote from a c++ book:

"It is a common mistake to hide a base class method when you intend to override it, by
forgetting to include the keyword const. const is part of the signature, and leaving it off
changes the signature, and thus hides the method rather than overrides it. "

Comment: Overloading: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_overloading, Overriding: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_overriding

Comment: second get in base missed the return type

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is neither overloading nor overriding. Rather, it is *hiding*.

If the other function were also visible, it *would* be overloading, which you can achieve with `using`:

```
class Derived  : public Base
{
public:
    using Base::get;
    int get();
};
```

Even if you declared `int get() const` in the derived class, it would merely be hiding the base function, since the base function is not `virtual`.

Comment: 1)so the only case of overriding is making the get function visible in Derived class ? <br/>
2) would not this give me an error because it's multiple definition ?

Comment: @AlexDan: No, the only way to override is to make `get` *virtual* and then declare another function in `Derived` with the same signature.

Comment: what about the method you mentioned earlier, with 'using' keyword. is this concedred overriding? and can you explain to me what's the use of the keyword 'using' inside the Derived class . and sorry all this question. thnks

Comment: @AlexDan: Oh dear, I'm sorry, that was a typo: I meant to say "overloading". With `using`, you allow both overloads to be visible. Fixed.

Answer (score 2):

1. Neither, it's just "hiding".
2. No.  Hiding occurs based on function name, not on function signature.

Your quote is only relevant if you've declared the base-class functions `virtual`; you cannot override a non-`virtual` function.

Comment: I read in a book this: Quote " It is a common mistake to hide a base class method when you intend to override it, by
forgetting to include the keyword const. const is part of the signature, and leaving it off
changes the signature, and thus hides the method rather than overrides it. " can you explain it to me. thanks

Answer (score 2):

Overloading is a function named the same, but with a different signature.

Overriding is overriding a signature that already exist.

You have just "hidden", which is neither.

A quick google search reveals this:
http://users.soe.ucsc.edu/~charlie/book/notes/chap7/sld012.htm which you may find helpful.

Comment: Overriding also requires the base function to be virtual.